# Inheriting a list from another WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program which has a main window already built, and I am adding a window called 'Profiler'. There is a list in the main window which I need to be able to use, therefore I need to use the main window as a base.

The first thing I did, was in the main window class I made the list I needed protected and created and get method :

```
 protected List<PaperRoll> paperRolls = new List<PaperRoll>(); 

    public List<PaperRoll> PaperRolls
    {
        get { return paperRolls; }
    }
```

Then in the profiler window,  I tried to use the main window (which is called DspWindow) as a base class:

```
 public partial class Profiler : DspWindow 
{
    public Profiler() : base ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<PaperRoll> pr = base.PaperRolls;


    }
}
```

This caused the error **Partial declarations of 'Profiler' must not specify different base classes** . I tried to research the error and it seeemed that this was because the xaml wasn't inheriting from the base class. Therefore, I changed to xaml to include the base class:

```
<base:DspWindow x:Class="DSP_Simulator.Profiler"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DSP_Simulator"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Profiler" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</base:DspWindow>
```

And this has caused multiple errors such as **'base:DspWindow' was not found**, **prefix 'base' is not defined** and **'base' is an undeclared prefix**. 
Please could someone tell me where I am going round?

Comment: you don't need to use it as a base class, just grab your main window instance  var main = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to understand how inheritance works.

Just because you want to use a member of a class in an object doesn't mean you have to inherit from it.

I don't think you want to use the definition but the value of the list, so I'd suggest that, instead of inheriting from the `DspWindow`, you should reference it in the `Profiler`.

I don't know how your windows work together but I guess that `DspWindow` creates a new `Profiler`, so I'd suggest, you could create a new `Profiler` object with a constructor that recieves the `DspWindow` as a parameter and then uses its instance internally.

```
public partial class Profiler : Window
{
    private DspWindow dspWindow;    

    public Profiler(DspWindow dspWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dspWindow = dspWindow;
    }

    void DoSomething() 
    {
        int numberOfPaperRolls = dspWindow.PaperRolls.Count; //you can access the list in this object aswell!
    }
}
```

And in the `DspWindow`:

```
var prof = new Profiler(this);
prof.Show();
```